# Checking if my script for health check works

Tags: python, fastapi

I wrote a simple script using FastAPI, `main.py` which is in `C:\Users\me`:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/health")
async def root():
       return {"message":"App is working"}
```

I created a virtual environment where I installed FastAPI and all the dependencies/packages around it. I activated the environment and simply ran `main.py`, but nothing happens, no error, no output. So it's just:

```
(myenv) (base) C:\Users\me>main.py

(myenv) (base) C:\Users\me>
```

It's probably a noob question and I'm new to this, but how do I know it works?

Comment: @Itworksonmypc same result, no error but no output either.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/) suggests that you should "pip install uvicorn" and run the following:

`uvicorn main:app --reload`

Comment: I get `DLL load failed while importing _ssl: The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: Is the error occuring when you run "pip install "uvicorn[standard]" or when you run "uvicorn main:app --reload"?

Comment: the latter, uvicorn got installed when I installed all the optionals for FastAPI.

Comment: It looks like a dependency issue. You can run "which python3" to check your python interpreter path, to make sure it is correct (if you have multiple python interpreters). You can try to make a hole new virtual environment and reinstall your dependencies using pip install.